# How to install OpenJDK 10 for Elasticsearch 6.4

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have just created a Solr 7.5 cluster with openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz in the following way.

```
curl -O https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar zxvf openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
mv jdk-10.0.2 /usr/local/java/

cat > /etc/profile.d/jdk10.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/java:/usr/local/java/bin
EOF

source /etc/profile.d/jdk10.sh
```

And Solr 7.5 are happy (;

Now I am trying to do the same with Elasticsearch 6.4 but I am getting this error:

```
which: no java in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin)
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
error: %pre(elasticsearch-0:6.4.2-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error: elasticsearch-0:6.4.2-1.noarch: install failed
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
Failed to start elasticsearch.service: Unit not found.
```

But java is set in the path and also JAVA_HOME

```
[root@ip-10-0-5-10 ~]# java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

echo $PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/java/bin:/usr/local/java:/root/bin
```

This works for root and the ec2-user. I know that the [OpenJDK 10.02 are supported](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm) so why can ES find java?
Looks like I should install it in one of this folders: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

Answer (score 0):

There could be many different reasons why `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` is not changed e.g. some other script overriding it after `/etc/profile.d/jdk10.sh` is executed. Since `/etc/profile.d` scripts should run on login maybe you simply haven't logged out? You didn't even provide the command that you are using to start Elastic Search, does it run under it's own user?

Take a look at [Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored) thread, the only way to figure it out is to debug this step by step.

Comment: JAVA_HOME has a value and java is also in the path, the are not overwritten. And I can not install Elastic's because of the java problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a user error (: I was using sudo to install elasticsearch that's why the java environment was empty.

If someone can find it useful then here is one way to install ES but without memory and plug-ins configurations.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# install java
curl -O https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar zxvf openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
mv jdk-10.0.2 /usr/local/open-jdk-10

cat > /etc/profile.d/jdk10.sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/open-jdk-10
export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/open-jdk-10/bin
EOF

source /etc/profile.d/jdk10.sh

# install elasticsearch
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo << EOF
[elasticsearch-6.x]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 6.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
EOF

# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
yum install elasticsearch -y
```